# Google Maps API error on mobile devices only: InvalidValueError

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have very irritating error with Google Maps Api. On desktop it works fine, but when I open the same page on mobile (or in Firefox/Chrome mobile view) the map loads fine, with marker on it (or just empty map), but when I try to move/zoom - map dissapear and I get this error in console: "InvalidValueError: setCenter: not a LatLng or LatLngLiteral with finite coordinates: in property lat: NaN is not an accepted value"

I've tryed with position as array, as new google.maps.LatLng(), lat and lon with parseFloat and without.

Earlier it worked fine, but from some days not.

**EDIT:** It happens only when I move - when I zoom (kliking on GM buttons, or double click map - it works)

My code:

```
<script async defer src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=**********&callback=initMap"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var map;
    function initMap() {
        var mapOptions = {
            streetViewControl: false,
            zoomControlOptions: {
                style: google.maps.ZoomControlStyle.SMALL
            },
            zoom: 5,
            center: new google.maps.LatLng(52.022935, 19.615378),
            mapTypeControlOptions: {
                mapTypeIds: []
            }
        };
        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('mapa'),mapOptions);
        // Try HTML5 geolocation.
    }
</script>
```

Comment: did you tryed to initialize this `new google.maps.LatLng(52.022935, 19.615378)` outside initMap(), and use it from a variable or from a parameter?

Comment: The posted code works for me in both Firefox and Chrome on Android ([fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/r4f91dcs/)).  Please provide a [mcve] that demonstrates your issue.

Comment: Ok, I found the bug. I don't know why, but now it works on my phone (Chrome), but on dektop with mobile view it doesn't. But only, when I pick Device like iPhone, or Galaxy, to set the view. When I change the size of the view (so it's custom) it works...